# Mis variables se cambian de lugar

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, web

Estoy haciendo un generador de pseudonumeros aleatorios pero al momento de hacer de imprimir la tabla, los resultados me los da bien en la interracion, pero en la columna de operacion me los marca con otros numeros, ejemplo: si ingresas como semillas 65,89,98,03,69, modulo 100 y cantidad 7. te debe mandar una tabla asi :

```
Xn  Fórmula Operación   Xn+1    Razón
X6  = (X0 + X5) mod 100 = (69 + 65) mod 100     = 34    r1 = 34/99 = 0.3434
X7  = (X1 + X6) mod 100 = (34 + 89) mod 100 = 23    r2 = 23/99 = 0.2323
X8  = (X2 + X7) mod 100 = (23+ 98) mod 100  = 21    r3 = 21/99 = 0.2121
X9  = (X3 + X8) mod 100 = (21 + 03) mod 100 = 24    r4 = 24/99 = 0.2424
X10 = (X4 + X9) mod 100 = (24 + 69) mod 100 = 93    r5 = 93/99 = 0.9393
X11 = (X5 + X10) mod 100    = (93+ 34) mod 100  = 27    r6 = 27/99 = 0.2727
X12 = (X6 + X11) mod 100    = (27+ 23) mod 100  = 50    r7 = 50/99 = 0.5050
```

Pero me manda la tabla con los resultados correctos pero  con la operacion mal, asi:

```
Xn  Fórmula Operación   Xn+1    Razón
X6  = (X0 + X5) mod 100 = (89 + 34) mod 100 = 34    r1 = 34/99 = 0.3434
X7  = (X1 + X6) mod 100 = (98 + 23) mod 100 = 23    r2 = 23/99 = 0.2323
X8  = (X2 + X7) mod 100 = (3 + 21) mod 100  = 21    r3 = 21/99 = 0.2121
X9  = (X3 + X8) mod 100 = (69 + 24) mod 100 = 24    r4 = 24/99 = 0.2424
X10 = (X4 + X9) mod 100 = (34 + 93) mod 100 = 93    r5 = 93/99 = 0.9393
X11 = (X5 + X10) mod 100    = (23 + 27) mod 100 = 27    r6 = 27/99 = 0.2727
X12 = (X6 + X11) mod 100    = (21 + 50) mod 100 = 50    r7 = 50/99 = 0.5050
Ya trate de varias formas, pero no me sale, de antemano porfavor y gracias!
```

```js
function generar() {
        const semillas = document.getElementById("semillas").value.split(",");
        const modulo = parseInt(document.getElementById("modulo").value);
        const cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value);
        
        const xn = semillas.map(Number);
        const resultados = [];
        const razones = [];
        const rSet = new Set();
        
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
          const suma = xn[0] + xn[xn.length - 1];
          const xn1 = suma % modulo;
          const rString = (xn1 / (modulo - 1)).toString();
          const r = rString.slice(0, rString.indexOf(".") + 5);
          resultados.push(xn1);
          razones.push(r);
          
          if (rSet.has(r)) {
            alert(`El valor de r=${r} se ha repetido, el ciclo se detendrá.`);
            break;
          }
          
          rSet.add(r);
          xn.shift();
          xn.push(xn1);
        
          const fila = document.createElement("tr");
          fila.innerHTML = `
            <td>X${i + semillas.length + 1}</td>
            <td>= (X${i} + X${i + semillas.length}) mod ${modulo}</td>
            <td>= (${xn[0]} + ${xn[xn.length - 1]}) mod ${modulo}</td>
            <td>= ${xn1}</td>
            <td>r${i+1} = ${xn1}/${modulo-1} = ${r}</td>
          `;
          document.getElementById("procedimiento").appendChild(fila);
        }
        
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = `
          <p>Números generados: ${resultados.join(", ")}</p>
          <p>Razones: ${razones.join(", ")}</p>
        `;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Algoritmo Congruencial Aditivo</h1>

        <label for="semillas">Semillas iniciales:</label>
        <input type="text" id="semillas" name="semillas" placeholder="Separadas por comas, ej: 65,89,98,03,69"><br>

        <label for="modulo">Módulo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="modulo" name="modulo" placeholder="Valor de m"><br>

        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de resultados:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" value="7"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="generar()">Generar</button>


    <table id="procedimiento">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Xn</th>
                <th>Fórmula</th>
                <th>Operación</th>
                <th>Xn+1</th>
                <th>Razón</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>
```

Ya le movi de diversas formas, pero no me sale.
En el archivo html solo tengo label e inputs para capturar los resultados, donde tengo todo el maquetado, y el en js uso solo vainilla js.
Pofavor y gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque antes de imprimir todo manipulas el array `xn` sacando el primero y colocando un nuevo último dato

```
xn.shift();
xn.push(xn1);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function generar() {
        const semillas = document.getElementById("semillas").value.split(",");
        const modulo = parseInt(document.getElementById("modulo").value);
        const cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value);
        
        const xn = semillas.map(Number);
        const resultados = [];
        const razones = [];
        const rSet = new Set();
        
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
          const suma = xn[0] + xn[xn.length - 1];
    
          const xn1 = suma % modulo;
          const rString = (xn1 / (modulo - 1)).toString();
          const r = rString.slice(0, rString.indexOf(".") + 5);
          resultados.push(xn1);
          razones.push(r);
          
          if (rSet.has(r)) {
            alert(`El valor de r=${r} se ha repetido, el ciclo se detendrá.`);
            break;
          }
          
          rSet.add(r);
          //xn.shift();
          //xn.push(xn1);
        
          const fila = document.createElement("tr");
          fila.innerHTML = `
            <td>X${i + semillas.length + 1}</td>
            <td>= (X${i} + X${i + semillas.length}) mod ${modulo}</td>
            <td>= (${xn[0]} + ${xn[xn.length - 1]}) mod ${modulo}</td>
            <td>= ${xn1}</td>
            <td>r${i+1} = ${xn1}/${modulo-1} = ${r}</td>
          `;
          document.getElementById("procedimiento").appendChild(fila);
          xn.shift();
          xn.push(xn1);
        }
        
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = `
          <p>Números generados: ${resultados.join(", ")}</p>
          <p>Razones: ${razones.join(", ")}</p>
        `;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Algoritmo Congruencial Aditivo</h1>

        <label for="semillas">Semillas iniciales:</label>
        <input type="text" id="semillas" name="semillas" placeholder="Separadas por comas, ej: 65,89,98,03,69" value="65,89,98,03,69"><br>

        <label for="modulo">Módulo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="modulo" name="modulo" placeholder="Valor de m" value="100"><br>

        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de resultados:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" value="7"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="generar()">Generar</button>


    <table id="procedimiento" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Xn</th>
                <th>Fórmula</th>
                <th>Operación</th>
                <th>Xn+1</th>
                <th>Razón</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, me ayudaste demasiado, gracias!